# minimizing the weighted summation of two sequences

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

how can I minimize the following function:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^na(i)x^2(i,j)b(j) $$
assuming
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x^2(i,j) = 1 , j=1..n$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^n x^2(i,j) = 1 , i=1..n$$

here x(i,j) are the variables and a(i) and b(j) are non increasing constant sequence of numbers

Comment: You can set all $a = 1$ and $b = -\infty$. That should do it.

Comment: So basically you want minimize the linear function $X\mapsto tr(ba^T X)$ where $X$ is doubly stochastic? Do you know the Birkhoff–von Neumann theorem? That the set of doubly stochastic matrices is a convex polytope with the set of permutation matrices as vertices?

Comment: yes It can be solved by representing X as combination of permutation matrices, but in fact I dont want to solve it in that manner.

Comment: do you mean that you don't want solve it as a linear program, or as a combinatoric problem? Without additional conditions on $a$ and $b$, I am not sure there is a analytic solution.

Comment: no, I just dont want to use the Birkhoff theorem, I am looking for other methods and theorems, that's why i didnt stated the problem as doubly stochastic matrix; however, representing X by a convex combination of permutation matrices, the answer can be easily derived which is X = reverse identity matrix, which is an analytic solution

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the problem as follows:

$$
\mbox{Minimize}\quad \sum_{i,j=1}^n c_{ij} y_{ij}
$$
subject to
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n y_{ij} = 1 \quad \forall j = 1,...,n\\
\sum_{j=1}^n y_{ij} = 1 \quad \forall i = 1,...,n
$$

where $y_{ij}=x^2(i,j)$ and $c_{ij}=a(i)b(j)$. Now, since $x^2(i,j)\ge 0$, you can assume $y_{ij}\ge 0$. This is a [minimum cost flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) (easy to solve) on a complete weighted bipartite graph $G=(V_1\times V_2,E)$ with :

- $V_1=V_2=\{1,...,n \}$
- $E= \{ (i,j)\; |\; i \in V_1, j \in V_2 \} $
- a weight function $\omega: (i,j) \rightarrow c_{ij}$ on each edge